# Internet via audio?

Tags: linux, terminal, audio, internet, modem

Alright, this may sound a little crazy, but let me explain.

I have 2 desktops, one with a broken Ethernet port, and one with a working one. Both have an analog audio input/output, are running Linux, have minimodem installed and can send data back and forth reliably at around 750 baud (but error correction would be very helpful). Since the two desktops can exchange data at the same time (one does not have to wait for receive to finish before sending) via analog stereo, it *should* be possible to get the desktop with the broken Ethernet port online, right? If so, how would I go about that? Would I have to use other software such as soundmodem, or other applications?

EDIT: I got it working with the answer below (at 1200 baud, <1% packet loss average), but it creates a **peer-to-peer** connection as opposed to an **internet** connection. How would I go about modifying the `ip` line to allow me to connect to the internet?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 750 baud? This takes you back to about 1982 in speeds. I was really happy about that time when my graduate lab upgraded from 600 to 1200 baud. A USB ethernet adapter costs ~$12US on amazon. Do you really want to wait 10 minutes to load a simple, contemporary web page?

Comment: @doneal24 I'm still trying higher and lower baud speeds to see which are most stable. And to answer your question, 100%. I really do not mind if it takes 10+ minutes to just load Google via elinks. Or about 500ms per keypress via SSH. But I can't really go higher than 1k baud due to a critical factor: CPU speed. My x64 Pentium 4 just can't keep up with higher baudrates.

Comment: Interesting indeed. I suppose you get a good reason for transmitting that way. I would almost certainly have tried first communicating via the serial ports thanks to PPP, expecting much higher bitrates.

Comment: "But I can't really go higher than 1k baud due to a critical factor: CPU speed" But...really? It's been a while since I worked on a Pentium 4, but my Commodore 64 could do 2400 bps just in software, and could hit 9600 bps with [some creative wiring and special drivers](https://www.pagetable.com/?p=1656). I'm surprised your P4 can't go faster.

Comment: @larsks My apologies, I meant 5k. Higher common baudrates (9600 for example) stutter badly. I don't know if it's PulseAudio or minimodem itself, but I do feel like something is off about it not being able to exceed that amount.

Comment: @doneal24 I did some testing and it actually, surprisingly only took 2 minutes to load the default apache2 webpage (3 including the Debian image) at **600** baud!

Comment: "How would I go about..." just add a default route on the leaf node and enable forwarding on the intermediate node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do it with SLIP.
Check out this project log from someone doing exactly that: https://xenoworld.de/knowledge/slip.html

Comment: This works great! Slowly increasing the baud speeds, currently at 600. But are there any other programs that can do this (such as [quiet](https://github.com/quiet/quiet))?

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question, it's essentially the same thing as setting up a LAN-to-WAN router, assuming you have a network link on the "LAN side" that your devices already recognize and agree on, as SLIP would provide. There are assuredly more details elsewhere, but the short of it (for IPv4) is as follows, assuming the router (with Internet access) has address local address `$ROUTER` and the client on the other end of the tunnel has address `$CLIENT` (all of this must run as `root`, or at least `CAP_NET_ADMIN` and possibly others):

```bash
# On $ROUTER:

# ask the kernel to forward packets it receives that aren't destined 
# for the local host:
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# when forwarding packets from the client, rewrite the source addresses,
# since our network segment isn't globally visible:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s $CLIENT/32 -j MASQUERADE
# (you might also set up some DNAT rules if you want to "port forward")

# On $CLIENT:

# be sure the router is always registered as a local route--it probably
# was when the interface was brought up, but just to be sure:
ip r add $ROUTER/32 dev $SLIPIF
# replace $SLIPIF with $CLIENT's name for the SLIP interface

# now tell the client that $ROUTER is happy to forward all other Internet
# traffic:
ip r add default via $ROUTER
```

Neither `$CLIENT` nor `$ROUTER` need to share an address space in this simple example, but you could see how this would be easily extended to a full LAN allocation if needed. You'll see all sorts of variants of this exact procedure--possibly with slightly different tools, like the BSD ones, or newer netfilter interfaces like `nftables`--all over the place, but the ideas expressed in the comments above will be essentially the same. One word of caution: if it doesn't work at first, try to make sure nothing else  (`systemd-networkd`, `NetworkManager`, etc.) is "managing" the SLIP interface, nor firewalls (like `ufw`) actively using netfilter; both of these tend to have some other idea of the configuration that can be in conflict with what you're doing, and might silently delete your routes or drop your packets.